# jQuery or javascript: Get dynamic div height in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works in Firefox/Safari but not on IE

```
var h = parseInt($('#elementWhichHeightCanChange').css('height'));
alert(h);
```

on IE it returns NaN.
Anyone know how to get div height depending on its content on IE?

I want to resize this popup window to fit the content, which currently works only on Firefox.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this, but it might work.

```
var h = $('#elementWhichHeightCanChange').height();
alert(h);
```

Use the [height function](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height) or [outerHeight](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerHeight#margin) instead of css height. You also won't need the parseInt() because this will return an integer, unlike css height.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var h = $('#elementWhichHeightCanChange').outerHeight();
alert(h);
```

This will include paddings and borders - things you probably want to take into account.